# New string in resx not available

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, resx

I added a new Resx-File last week to my project, which worked fine. It was possible to access the resource strings in xaml, but today I have added some more strings and visual studio can not found the new resource strings. It's the same file. The old strings are available.
I tried already the rebuild of the solution, but did not help.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried closing the xaml file where you are using the string and then rebuilding your solution?

Comment: Yes, after this. I got a lot more errors. -.-